# mat-select multiple set the checked options from an array, Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, select

Angular 4.

I need help to set the options of a mat-select so here is the problem:

1.First I got two variables: `options` and `checkedOptions`

```
options: string[];
checkedOptions: string[] //This comes from the BD;
```

2.So options are all the options and checkedOptions comes from the BD, something like this:

```
options = ["o1", "o2", "o3", "o4", ... "oN"]
checkedOptions = ["o2", "o4"]
```

3.I print the options like this:

```
<mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="always" color="accent" class="input-all">
  <mat-select multiple placeholder="{{ par.label }}">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let op of options" [value]="op">{{ op }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

4. So in the mat-select are all the options... but what I want is, in th `options` list, just check which are in the `checkedOptions` list. How do I do that?

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use ngModel inside your mat-select-tag and bind it to your selection list, in this case. Here is the solution:

HTML

```
<mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="always" color="accent" class="input-all">

   <mat-select [(ngModel)]="checkedOptions" multiple placeholder="{{ par.label }}">

       <mat-option *ngFor="let op of options" [value]="op">{{ op }}</mat-option>

   </mat-select>

</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but that code didn't work. I see this error "Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'checked' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-option'."

Comment: Sorry mate for answering that late. I had to do some research as Material is a little tricky to handle. Please have a look at my updated post. I already tested it via StackBlitz. It works.